# Homebrew pyenv install error dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pyenv, libreadline

After installing pyenv from Homebrew on MacOS Mojave I am getting build errors when attempting to install any python versions.

When running `pyenv install` for any version the build will fail with error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ln -sf /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Comment: Be careful using the the force flag `-f` as it could overwrite a working install. If you get an error with `-s`. Try checking what the link is pointing to with `ls -l` before overwriting it.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to force link the readline 8 lib that I had under `/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/`.

```
> cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
> ls
libhistory.8.0.dylib  libhistory.a          libreadline.8.dylib   libreadline.dylib
libhistory.8.dylib    libhistory.dylib      libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.a         pkgconfig
```

Since I have a newer version of the readline lib, I tried to force it to find the one I have by symlinking it to the filename it was looking for. e.g.

```
> cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
> ln -s libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
> ls
libhistory.8.0.dylib  libhistory.a          libreadline.7.dylib   libreadline.8.dylib   libreadline.dylib
libhistory.8.dylib    libhistory.dylib      libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.a         pkgconfig
```

`pyenv install x.y.z` should now be working (or at least throw a different error ;).