# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code,Xcode 10.1 dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, homebrew

I had this error when I was trying to build and run my iOS app on Xcode, I tried restarting my Mac nothing worked then I later searched for other error which was `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib`

The problem could have arose after updating brew

Finally I found a solution here [Answer by Goran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776973/5355624), Hope you will find it helpful.

Hope you will find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

here is the copy of the answer that worked for me

```
# cd /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/
# ln -s libreadline.8.0.dylib libreadline.7.dylib
# ls
libhistory.8.0.dylib  libhistory.a          libreadline.7.dylib    libreadline.8.dylib   libreadline.dylib
libhistory.8.dylib    libhistory.dylib      libreadline.8.0.dylib  libreadline.a
```

Can read more about the answer by [Goran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776973/5355624)

Comment: So qou created a q/a pair that duplicates another SO Q&A. Why? _You_ found your solution using the other question - what makes your Q&A "better" to solve this? As is it is a duplicates and will be downvoted and closed as dupe... what "worth"  has your copied answer in and above what Groan  answered?

Comment: I actually wanted to comment on the (first question) about the solution because all the solutions which are there did not work except this one which I found somewhere and it happened the comments were closed that question (the first one).

So I decided to recreate the question so that other people who might have the similar problem can find it easily. 

Yes I did not only copy the answer but I also stated the source and redirected people to go to the source. Besides it was under different context but it still worked, I therefore see it no problem to share with people what worked for me.